# PHP check if date between two dates

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, date, time

i have code in php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$dt         = new DateTime('first Saturday of this month');
$periode1   = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
$periode11  = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "$periode1 +6 day" ) );

$tgl_delivered  = "2015-07-10";
if (($tgl_delivered >= $periode1) && ($tgl_delivered <= $periode11)){
$tanggal_periode="$periode1 | $periode11";
}
echo "$tanggal_periode";
```

and the result is "2015-08-08 | 2015-08-14";

however i want this result be "2015-07-04 | 2015-07-10"
whats wrong with my code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
function getTanggalPeriod($tglDelivered)
{
    $data=explode("-",$tglDelivered);
    $periode1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('First Saturday '.date('F o', @mktime(0,0,0, $data[1], 1, $data[0]))));
    $periode11 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($periode1.' +6 day'));
    if (($tglDelivered >= $periode1) && ($tglDelivered <= $periode11))
    {
        echo $tanggal_periode="$periode1 | $periode11";
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Not OK';
    }
} 
$tglDelivered = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("2015-07-10")); // Make sure of maintain the date format.
getTanggalPeriod($tglDelivered);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not trust the string conversion. Instead I'll compute the weekday of the first day of the month:

```
$day1=mktime(0,0,0,date('n'),1,date('Y');
$dow=date('w',$day1);
```

And figure out the first Saturday:

```
$sat = (6-$dow)*3600*24+$day1;
```

Delivery day is 6 days apart:

```
$delivery = $sat + 3600*24*6;
```

Can you try the code with the above values?

Comment: ups sorry maybe i mean i want the result be "2015-07-04 | 2015-07-10".. cz the first saturday until +6 days after saturday

Comment: If looking strictly at the title of the question, the other answer might have answered your question. But looking at your code, I think the bug source is how the date variables are computed. Now you have correct time stamps, it's a matter of value comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this function:

```
function checkBetweenDates($date, $start, $end) {
    $dateValue  = new DateTime($date);
    $startValue = new DateTime($start);
    $endValue   = new DateTime($end);

    return ($dateValue >= $startValue && $dateValue <= $endValue);
}

/* function return true or false */
var_dump(checkBetweenDates('first Saturday of this month', '2015-07-04', '2015-07-10'));
```

Comment: ups sorry maybe i mean i want the result be "2015-07-04 | 2015-07-10".. cz the first saturday until +6 days after saturday

Comment: ok, sorry, i changed the first parameter already, try now please.